# Match regex up to {

Tags: regex

I got a text filled with stuff. I want to match every occurrence of `msg` up to a `{`.

My regex looks like this `regex = re.compile('"msg".+"{"')`.

According to my understanding this should match `msg` directly, and then anything one or more times up to `{`.

No results are yielded however. If I only use `msg` it prints that out, but i need the whole result printed (up to the {).

I tried to use `.{14}` but since the number of characters always differ, this is to no avail.

Comment: If there are multiple `{`s on a line, do you want to match until the first one or until the last one?

Comment: I would uses `^[^{]*`

Comment: When things don't work, try going simpler. Try writing a regex that just matches "msg", then build on it

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `{` like this: `\{`. `{` is a valid regex character, so you need to escape it, otherwise, regex will try and use its special meaning. Escaping it will mean that regex matches the `{` character literally. Otherwise, your regex looks fine.

Comment: That is not always true: https://regex101.com/r/dzgBuJ/1, `msg.+{` is a perfect valid expression in `Python`.